# Power failure during ubuntu installation killed my drive

Tags: system-installation

Well, things eat really bad in the last hour. 
I have two ocz ssd. 
On one windows 7 is installed, on the second I tried 
To install ubuntu 11.10.
Now my ssd is not recognizable (also on the bios) 
Nd I can't login to windows (but know how to fix that... Maybe..) 
Ny ideas bout the drive? 
Thanks! 
Unlucky roy

Answer (score 2):

Your not being able to boot into Windows is almost certainly caused by GRUB2 having overwritten the MBR, but not having had time to run update-grub before the power failure. Fixing it should be as simple as booting into a Windows install disc and choosing "repair".

The SSD not being detected is trickier, but I have an idea. Is the drive Sandforce 2K based? Is it at least four months old? Had you updated its firmware recently?

IFF the answers to these questions are y/y/n, you have most likely been affected by an infamous bug in the Sandforce controller's firmware, which has been known to cause exactly the issue you describe. If so, fixing it should be as simple as cutting power to the drive completely for a few minutes. If not, I'd say to RMA it.